# Is it safe to accept the security certificate from AOL chat?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Is it safe to accept the security certificate from AOL chat? Did they recently change their  certificates? These images are from Pidgin.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about customer support for an application.

Comment: There's no way for us to tell if this is any more valid than you can tell.  You'd need to contact AOL out of band to find out if they changed it or not.  You could also view the certificate and see if it appears to be from a reputable Certificate Authority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue for Pidgin, related to the root certificates that are trusted, although it looks like it has been resolved:

https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/15850

I'm not certain whether updating Pidgin will therefore fix this, or you have to import a certificate yourself...

> People experiencing the AIM certificate problem can save this file to Pidgin's ca-certs directory: ​https://hg.pidgin.im/pidgin/main/raw-file/4e027bce3693/share/ca-certs/Entrust.net_2048.pem
>   For me that's /usr/share/purple/ca-certs/

To confirm that the certificate is in fact valid, you can check it using a service like [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) (or from your own box using something like [SSLyze](https://github.com/iSECPartners/sslyze) maybe). We know that Pidgin is trying to connect over 443 so this works.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.oscar.aol.com&s=64.12.235.15

This service reveals that the certificate presented by the server is valid, although you should make sure that you're receiving the same certificate that SSL Labs did. You can do this by comparing the fingerprint (3d9b06d38685972da2515ffb6a5629706d7ec698) from your screenshot to the first SHA1 value in the SSL Labs report. Since these are the same we can be pretty certain that you are talking to the correct server.

Comment: That's a really neat tool (SSL Labs). I'll use that for my own site.